# MVVM issue with binding a combobox to a datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid, combobox

I have sort of a Master/Details view.  I have some text boxes and a combo box bound to the selected item of the data grid.  What I want is the text boxes and the combo box to populate with the data from the data grid when a row is selected.  This part works fine.  The issue I am having is when I change the value of the combo box the data grid field is not updating.  I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, but it appears that I have something wrong.  The data grid holds records of type user and the combo box in question has records of type role.  The User entity has a navigation property to a RoleID.  How can I ensure that the data grid will update when changing the role combo box in the details?

Thank you,

RG

Here is the XAML...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Compliance.Views.UserAdministrationView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Compliance"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Compliance.Views"
         xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Compliance.Helpers"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Compliance.ViewModels"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <helpers:ActiveStatusConverter x:Key="ActiveStatusConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15">
        <Label Content="User" Height="25" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=usersDG, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="35" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <telerik:Label Content="User Name: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="180" >
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="UserName" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </TextBox.Text>                    
            </TextBox> 
            <telerik:Label Content="First Name: " Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="180">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="FirstName" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <telerik:Label Content="Last Name: " Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="180">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="LastName" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <telerik:Label Content="Email: " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="180" MaxWidth="180">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Email" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <telerik:Label Content="Active Status: " Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="comBoxActiveStatus" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="23" MinWidth="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ActiveStatus, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ActiveStatusConverter}, 
                                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                                    ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
                                    NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    EmptyText="Please Set Active Status">
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
            <telerik:Label Content="Role: " Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cmbRoles" 
                        Grid.Column="5" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        MinHeight="23" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Margin="5" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        MinWidth="180" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="RoleName" 
                        SelectedValue="{Binding RoleID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectedValuePath="RoleID"
                        EmptyText="Please Choose A Role">
            <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="Save User" Width="100"  />
            <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Content="Add User"  Width="100"  />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Users" Grid.Row="0" Height="25" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="usersDG" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" Header="User Name" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First Name" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last Name" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Role.RoleName, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Role Name" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ActiveStatus, Converter={StaticResource ActiveStatusConverter}}" Header="Active Status" />
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Some properties or controls do not default to `Mode=TwoWay`. I would check if that solves your problem first.

Comment: I do have Mode Two-Way set.

Comment: It would help if you post some source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ComboBox` bindings looks strange

You have `ItemsSource="{Binding }"` which suggests that the DataContext for the `ComboBox` is a collection of Role objects, however you also have `SelectedValue="{Binding RoleID}`, which suggests the `DataContext` contains a property called `RoleId`

In addition, your `GridView` binds to `Role.RoleName`, so I would expect you'd want to bind your `ComboBox.SelectedValue` to `Role.RoleId` or perhaps `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to the property `Role` if they reference the same `Role` object in memory.

So I would expect your ComboBox bindings to look something like

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:StaticLists.RoleList}}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Role.RoleID}" ... />
```

or something like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:UserAdministrationView}},
              Path=DataContext.AvailableRoles}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Role}" ... />
```

I'd suggest looking into what your `ComboBox.DataContext` is (I use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) for debugging things like this), and double-check that your bindings are correct

Comment: Hi Rachel.  The ItemsSource for the ComboBox is bound to a list of Roles pulled from the database.  The datagrid is bound to an ObservableCollection of Users which has a navigation property of RoleID.  I have bound the Text Boxes and the ComboBox to the datagrid selected item.  When I click on a row in the datagrid the text boxes and the combobox change appropriately.  Changing the data in the text boxes updates the row in the datagrid, but changing the combobox does not update the role in the datagrid.  This is where I am having issues.

Comment: @user1599271 Its hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your exact code, however there are a few things to try. First, if your `ComboBox.SelectedValue` is bound to User.RoleId, then make sure that changing `User.RoleId` is triggering a `PropertyChange` notification for `User.Role` since that is what your DataGrid is bound to. Second, you could try binding `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to `User.Role` instead, however for that to work be sure that they both point to the same object reference, or overwrite the `Role.Equals()` method to consider an object the same if the Ids match

Comment: @user1599271 And last of all, it could be a quirk with Telerik's `GridView` control (I've discovered some strange quirks with their WPF controls in the past), where the property doesn't update with a `PropertyChange` notification on `Role`, and it needs a PropertyChange notification for `Role.RoleName` instead. So you could try triggering the property change notification for `User.Role.RoleName` manually whenever `User.RoleId` changes.